# Map a domain object from a third party application or a different bounded context

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm tasked with developing an application which is going to track what an end user does in a session.

My application doesn't handle user registration or anything related to user. The user management is a different bounded context(a separate micro service in my case.) But my application would need to identify an user from a user card(my application would receive the card information.). I would need to call the User micro service with the card information to get user details back. And with the details received, I would need to apply business rules(these rules are part of my domain) to verify if this user can create a session or not.

What I'm not not sure is whether the User is my domain or not. Right now I have added a service in my Infrastructure layer to get the user details from the User service. From the Application layer where I'd get the request, I'd talk to the Infrastructure service to get the user details and should I map this response to my domain layer to execute business rules?

Edit:
My confusion is getting the user information is not part of my domain. I have to to fetch these details from a separate microservice. But I would have to apply business rules on the details received from the microservice. I'm not clear on where to place these business rules.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Common library for classes and communication between microservices?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/416475/common-library-for-classes-and-communication-between-microservices)

Comment: @guillaume31 Not really. I have added further explanation in my question.

Comment: If it's the responsibility of your bounded context to apply these rules and they are business rules, why wouldn't they be in your BC's Domain layer? I don't understand.

Comment: Getting the user information from the card details is not my application's concern. But the business logic/rules to check whether the user is eligible is my application's concern. Should I directly inject a service in my domain layer and encapsulate the "getting users" part and then apply the business rule?

Comment: You need to make the distinction between "getting the user" and "applying business rules based on user data to determine if (X)". They are not necessarily in the same layer. Normally the domain layer should be free of things like "fetching this", "sending that to external system", etc.

Comment: Also, your edit is very confusing because the Q title and `should I map this response to my domain layer to execute business rules?` seem to point in one direction, the edit in another direction (the question of where to place the business rules).

Comment: That's the confusion I have as well. I know that domain layer should be free of such things. So my infrastructure layer has the logic to get the user. Now I have user details in my application layer. The rules to be applied on these details should be kept in my domain layer. How would I enforce these rules in my application layer? Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't get too hung up on where the data comes from. You have rules that need to be applied to user data. Your session management micro service can have its own `User` if need be. So you are copying some data from another service. This is a means to an end. Something in your infrastructure layer needs to get this information and hand it off as some business class. The important thing is your `User` object should not replicate *behavior* from another service. Copying data isn't the problem.

If there is any issue to fix, it's that the session management service has a hard dependency on the user registration service. If the registration service goes down, session management goes down too. Your session management service is no longer independently deployable — a violation of one of the core attributes of a micro service.

Instead of worrying about the concept of a "user" being spread across multiple services, consider:

- Maybe these two services should be combined, rendering this question moot.
- Or the session management service should subscribe to events from the registration service to copy relevant user information into its own database. Then you eliminate the hard dependency on the registration service.

  - And it should subscribe to updates to user information too, so the two services stay in sync.
  - The registration service should be the source of truth for user information, with the session management service keeping downstream copies of data. If either service disagrees about user information, the registration service wins the argument.

There is a frequent misunderstanding that micro services should be small. Sometimes two different areas of your business are so dependent on one another it makes no sense to separate them. On the other hand, the cost to keep these things independent of one another is data replication and synchronization.

Whichever you chose, the session management service has its own concept of a "user" that, by coincidence, has the same information. There is nothing wrong with multiple services having a class named `User` as long as they *behave* differently.

Comment: I keep referring to your application as a session management service, although after another read through your question, I'm not sure what to call it. If you have a different name, I can update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response. We have decided to proceed with the hard dependency approach for now. I'm going to follow the anti-corruption layer pattern and translate User data from the external system into my domain object and execute business rules.

Comment: @user1890098: that doesn't sound like an anti-corruption layer. Your suggested structure is pretty typical. Call web service, get JSON back, map to DTO, map DTO to business class, execute business logic. We've all certainly done worse things with nicer technology.

Comment: From my limited understanding, put all that in a service class(except the executing business logic), the service class becomes an anti-corruption layer facade. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/anti-corruption-layer

Comment: @user1890098: an anti-corruption layer implies you are building a better structured layer on top of an undesirable design. Mapping data from one type to another is just mapping data. An anti-corruption layer is concerned with adapting behavior, not data.